# How to use PlotOutput with grid.arrange in shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive-programming

This is my list of plots that I want to arrange using grid.arrange.

```
p <- lapply(1:10, function(i) doPlot(comb_labels[1, i], comb_labels[2, i]))
```

The plots generated using doPlot respond to changes in brush and hover reactive variables in Shiny.

Apparantly, the brush and hover can only be declared with PlotOutput like:

```
plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250, hover = "plot_hover", brush = "plot_brush", click = "plot_click")
```

I would like to have the plots in a custom grid like this:

```
grid.arrange(p[[1]], ng, ng, ng,
                     p[[2]], p[[3]], ng, ng,
                     p[[4]], p[[5]], p[[6]] , ng,
                     p[[7]], p[[8]], p[[9]], p[[10]])
```

This returns an image without any dynamic elements.

**How do I integrate the grid.arrange with PlotOutput or is there any alternative?**

The format of my code looks like this: https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415

Answer (score 4):

Save value returned by `grid.arrange` and then `print` it:

```
output$shinyPlotObject <- renderPlot({

   ...
   p = grid.arrange(p[[1]], ng, ng, ng,
                    p[[2]], p[[3]], ng, ng,
                    p[[4]], p[[5]], p[[6]] , ng,
                    p[[7]], p[[8]], p[[9]], p[[10]])

   print(p)
}
```